# Find coefficient for $x^{10}$ in $x^3(x^2-3x^3-1)^6$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, multinomial-coefficients

I'm trying to solve the following problem:

> Find the coefficient for  $x^{10}$ in $x^3(x^2-3x^3-1)^6$.

Can I use the multinomial theorem to solve it? I'm unsure how to start..

Thanks!

Comment: @Moo but what should I do with the $x^3$ before the brackets?

Comment: @Moo no, could you explain?

Comment: Yes you can use concept of multinomial also. Rather I feel that would be easiest approach.

Comment: @mathsdiscussion.com and how do I use the multinomial theorem?

Comment: The searched coefficient is $$180$$

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner and how did you calculate it?

Comment: @John you can easily find the formula here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem#Multinomial_coefficients

Comment: @ClementYung but how do I work with the $x^3$ before the brackets?

Comment: Divide both expressions by $x^3$. Then you're looking for the coefficient of the $x^7$ term in $(x^2-3x^3-1)^6$.

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner Isn't it -180?

Comment: @John no, it should be 180

Comment: The method is given in the link given earlier also I have posted this link please check if any dought on method do ask . In particular Question 2 in link.    https://www.mathsdiscussion.com/distribution-of-identical-objects-into-distinct-groups/

Answer (score 3):

After simplifying by $x^3$, you need to solve the Diophantine system

$$\begin{cases}a+b+c&=6,\\2a+3b+0c&=7.\end{cases}$$

The only solution is $a=2,b=1,c=3.$

Then the requested coefficient is, by the multinomial formula,

$$\binom{6!}{2!1!3!}1^2(-3)^1(-1)^3=180.$$

Comment: @user90369: non-negative. Just notice that by the second equation, $3b$ is one of $7,5,3,1$.

Comment: @user90369: the OP is already aware of the multinomial formula.

Answer (score 2):

*Definition:*

$[x^n]f(x)~$ means the coefficient of $~x^n~$ of the Taylor expansion of $~f(x)~$ at $~x=0~$ .

*Calculation:*

$\displaystyle [x^{10}]x^3(x^2-3x^3-1)^6 = [x^{7}](x^2-3x^3-1)^6 = [x^{7}]\sum\limits_{k=0}^6 {\binom 6 k}x^{2k}(3x-1)^k = $

$\displaystyle =\sum\limits_{k=0}^6 {\binom 6 k}[x^{7-2k}](3x-1)^k =\sum\limits_{~~~~~k=0\\0\leq 7-2k\leq k}^6 {\binom 6 k}[x^{7-2k}](3x-1)^k$

$\displaystyle =\sum\limits_{k=3}^3 {\binom 6 k}[x^{7-2k}](3x-1)^k = {\binom 6 3}[x^{1}](3x-1)^3 =20\cdot 3{\binom 3 1}=180$

Answer (score 1):

Well it's simple

we are multiplying every term by $x^3$ so coefficient of $x^{10}$ should be coeffiecent of $x^7$ in the expansion of $(x^2-3x^3-1)^6$

Now, divide three terms into two groups $((x^2-3x^3)+(-1))^6$

To get $x^7$, the only combination possible is when $x^2$ is raised to the power two and $-3x^3$ is rased to the power one and multiplied.So we get $6C3*(x^2-3x^3)^{(2+1)}*(-1)^{(6-(2+1))}$. I took 3 (2+1) because thats when i get the terms $x^7$.. for $x^7$ we get $6C3*3C2*(x^2)^2*(-3x^3)*(-1)^3$.Now multiply all the coefficent we get $20*3*-3*-1=180$

And you got your answer

Comment: I'm not sure that's really so interesting that the question is easy to answer. I think it's more of interest to find an understandable solution. While I'm aware that $6C3$ means ${\binom 6 3}$, your spelling is not widely known.