# Find coefficient of $x^{10}$ in $x^2(x^2-3x^3-1)^6$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, multinomial-theorem

I'm trying to solve the following problem (final exams preparation):

> Find coefficient of $x^{10}$ in $x^2(x^2-3x^3-1)^6$.

The steps I have taken so far:

$x^2(x^2-3x^3-1)^6 = $

$=x^2\sum \binom{6}{n1,n2,n3}(x)^{2n_1}(-3)^{n_2}(x)^{3n_2}(-1)^{n_3}$

$n_1+n_2+n_3=6$

$2n_1+3n_2=8$

$\Rightarrow$ $n_1=1 \wedge n_2=2$

$\Rightarrow$ $n_1=4 \wedge n_2=0$

Are my steps correct? If so, how do I continue?

Thanks

Comment: Looking good! Yes, those are the only two possibilities: $8=2+3+3$ or $8=2+2+2+2$. So what is the sum of those two terms?

Comment: @almagest Is the coefficient $\binom{6}{1,2,3}*(-3)^2*(-1)^3 + \binom{6}{4,0,2}*(-1)^2 = -525$?

Comment: Looks ok to me.

Comment: Duplicate under the *same title:* [Find coefficient for $x^{10}$ in $x^3(x^2-3x^3-1)^6$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3436779/find-coefficient-for-x10-in-x3x2-3x3-16)

Comment: @Hanno, not exactly a duplicate, the new question has $x^2$ outside the brackets, the old one had $x^3$ – but, close enough.

Comment: Thanks @GerryMyerson , that's right. My click was too quick.

Comment: The marked duplicate can be solved in pretty much the same way, so I'll vote to close too.

Answer (score 0):

I'll translate the work you did into English.

So the coefficient of the $x^{10}$ term in $x^2(x^2-3x^3-1)^6$ is the same as the coefficient of the $x^8$ term in $(x^2-3x^3-1)^6$.  To figure out which terms in that trinomial power contribute that that term, we effectively want to find the non-negative solutions to $2a+3b+c=8$ and $a+b+c=6$.  As you note, the solutions to that are $(a,b,c)\in\{(4,0,2),(1,2,3)\}$.

Our last step is appealing to the multinomial formula to find those two terms.  They are
$$\frac{6!}{4!2!}(x^2)^4(-3x^3)^0(-1)^2=15x^8\\\frac{6!}{3!2!}(x^2)^1(-3x^3)^2(-1)^3=90\cdot x^2\cdot9x^6\cdot(-1)=-540x^8$$
which lead to a total coefficient of $15-540=-525$.